# Lync 2013 Presence Indicators - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part, lync

I'm currently trying to code web parts to display a button to open a Lync chat window and also show the person's Lync presence. I have had some success using this code:

```
<div style="text-align: center"><a href="sip:person1@world.com"><img alt="test" src="maleicon.jpg" unlockratio="false" style="margin: 1px; width: 50px; height: 42px"/></a></div>

<div style="text-align: center"><span class="ms-imnSpan"><a class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" href="#"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img name="imnmark" title="" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-offline-10x10x32" id="imn_1,type=smtp" alt="Offline" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" sip="person1@world.com" showofflinepawn="1"></span></a></span><span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><a class="ms-subtleLink" href="#"></a></span>

<div style="text-align: center"><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-6-0"><strong>&#160;Person1</strong></span></div>
```

The top line of code gives the icon and allows click to open Lync for the specific SIP - I have no issues with this part, and the 3rd line just displays the persons name under the presence indicator.

The issue lies with line 2 - the presence indicator "freezing" on a status and then never updating again and also with some people it shows the full `spimn.png` without selecting a specific status. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.